# matplotlib argument 'left' must be 1 or scalar python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i try to plot the gantt chart, somebody can help me where is my mistake, my code looks like this:

```
pos = np.arange(4)+0.5
ax.barh(pos, [4.629627, 0.000011, 6.994444, 3.472222], 
       align = 'center', left=[735661.2, 735661.3, 735661.4, 735661.5], 
       height=0.5, color='m', alpha=0.9)
```

My script always finish with next error:

```
AssertionError: Incompatible sizes: argument 'left' must be length 1 or scalar
```

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` are you using? I cannot reproduce this issue with `1.4.3`

Comment: This error should only arise if `pos` and `left` do not have the same length. Could it be possible, that you overwrite `pos` somewhere in your script and at the time of calling `ax.barh` it is actually a scalar, not a vector?

Comment: hm.. Maybe something wrong with pos, i will double check this, but looks like everythink ok. Thank you for your advice